# Get values from a nested list with a LINQ expression

Tags: c#, list, linq

I want to write the value `_values (Freezer 01, Freezer 02, Freezer 03)` from the following nested list into a `List<string>`, unfortunately I have no idea how to accomplish this.

[image]

Comment: Is this Linq-to-Entities or Linq-to-Objects?

Comment: What exactly is `FluxTable` and why is LinqPad giving you a "Columns" and "Records" view? I'm unfamiliar with that library.

Comment: I use the following library to implement queries on an InfluxDB. https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-csharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Updated answer:

- Use `.SelectMany` to flatten nested lists.
- Use `TryGetValue` to simultaneously check if `"_value"` exists in a record's `Values` dictionary *and* to extract the value and return it in a `ValueTuple`.
- Then use `Where(...).Select(...)` to eliminate cases where `TryGetValue` failed.
- This code iterates over all `FluxTable` objects (and then over *all* `FluxRecord` objects in each table). If you only want to iterate over a single table (which will make the Linq query faster) then first extract the single table with `FluxTable theTable = tables.Single( /*predicater*/ );`.

  - The documentation for `FluxTable` makes it seem like there's no "Table name" property - that's weird...

```
List<FluxTable> tables = ...

List<String> values = tables
    .SelectMany( fluxTable => fluxTable.Records )
    .Select( fluxRecord => ( ok: fluxRecord.Values.TryGetValue( "_value", out String? str ), str ) )
    .Where( t => t.ok )
    .Select( t => t.str )
    .ToList();
```

#### Original answer for concatenated output

(I originally misread your post as if you were asking how you could get the output to a single `String` value)

Annoyingly, `String.Join` is not exposed as an extension-method for `IEnumerable<String>`, but if you *do* define it it makes things easier...

So add this to your code:

```
public static String StringJoin( this IEnumerable<String?> source, String separator ) 
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach( String? s in source )
    {
        _ = sb.Append( s ?? String.Empty );
        _ = sb.Append( separator );
    }

    if( sb.Length > 0 ) sb.Length -= separator.Length;

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Then do this:

```
List<FluxTable> tables = ...
String allValues = tables
    .SelectMany( fluxTable => fluxTable.Records )
    .Select( fluxRecord => ( ok: fluxRecord.Values.TryGetValue( "_value", out String? str ), str ) )
    .Where( t => t.ok )
    .Select( t => t.str )
    .StringJoin( separator: ", " );

Console.WriteLine( allValues ); // "Freezer 01, Freezer 02, Freezer 03"
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I get the message cannot convert from 'out string' to 'out object', _value is an object and not a string. Do you have any other idea how I can work around this?

Comment: var values = fluxTables
                         .SelectMany(fluxTable => fluxTable.Records)
                         .Select( FluxRecord => FluxRecord.GetValueByKey("_value"))
                         .ToList();

Answer (score 0):

FluxRecord provides the method `GetValueByKey`. This is how it worked now:

```
var values = fluxTables.SelectMany(fluxTable => fluxTable.Records) 
                       .Select( FluxRecord => FluxRecord.GetValueByKey("_value")) 
                       .ToList();
```

https://influxdata.github.io/influxdb-client-csharp/api/InfluxDB.Client.Core.Flux.Domain.FluxRecord.html#InfluxDB_Client_Core_Flux_Domain_FluxRecord_GetValueByKey_System_String_